# I'm trying to create a new dataframe based on a different dataframe using an if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know how I can apply an if statement on a row of a dataframe. All columns consists of strings like so:

```
d = {'emp' : {'Breakdown' : '11/12/2019', 'expl' : '123'}, 'emp2': {'Breakdown' : '11/03/2020', 'expl' : '123'}, 'emp3' : {'Breakdown' : '31/12/2019', 'expl' : '123'}, 'emp4' : {'Breakdown' : '31/12/2020', 'expl' : '123'}}

d1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

So I made it into a dataframe d and I want to try to make a new dataframe from the strings that contains '2020'.
I tried this:

```
df = {}

for t in d:
   df = d1[t]
   if '2020' in df.get('Breakdown'):
       ...
```

I also tried `df.loc[: 'Breakdown']`. This gives me two values `11/03/2020` and `31/12/2020`. So from here I don't really know what to do. I want it to look like this:

```
new_d = {'emp2' : {'Breakdown' : '11/03/2020', 'expl' : '123'}, 'emp4' : {'Breakdown' : '31/12/2020', 'expl' : '123'}}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_d)
```

Maybe this is a bit above my level of programming but I like to experiment with dataframes. I'm still playing around with the code so if I come up with a solution I'll obviously edit it here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to create a boolean mask then use this mask with [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter the corresponding columns:

```
df = d1.loc[:, d1.loc['Breakdown'].str.contains('2020')]
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
                 emp2        emp4
Breakdown  11/03/2020  31/12/2020
expl              123         123
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shubham Sharma. It did in fact work for me.